# Oxford Dictionary Api Search Word Through EditText

Tags: android

MainActivivity.java

```
package com.example.anubhav.notesapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
String url;
EditText et;
TextView t1;
Button btn;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    url = dictionaryEntries();
}

public void requestApiButtonClick(View v)
{
    MyDictionaryRequest myDictionaryRequest = new MyDictionaryRequest(this,t1);
    myDictionaryRequest.execute(url);

}

private String dictionaryEntries() {
    final String language = "en";
    final String word = et.getText().toString();
    final String word_id = word.toLowerCase();
    return "https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com:443/api/v1/entries/" + language + "/" + word_id;
}
```

}

DictionaryRequest.java

```
public class MyDictionaryRequest extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,String> {

final String app_id = "your_apiId";
final String app_key = "Your api_key";
String myurl;
TextView t1;

Context context;


Handler h = new Handler();
MyDictionaryRequest(Context context,TextView t1){
    this.context = context;
    this.t1=t1;


}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

    myurl = strings[0];
    try {
        URL url = new URL(myurl);
        HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("app_id",app_id);
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("app_key",app_key);

        // read the output from the server
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
        }

        return stringBuilder.toString();

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return e.toString();
    }
}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);

    String def;

    try{
        JSONObject js = new JSONObject(s);
        JSONArray results = js.getJSONArray("results");

        JSONObject lentries = results.getJSONObject(0);
        JSONArray lArray= lentries.getJSONArray("lexicalEntries");

        JSONObject entries = lArray.getJSONObject(0);
        JSONArray e = entries.getJSONArray("entries");

        JSONObject senses = e.getJSONObject(0);
        JSONArray sensesArray = senses.getJSONArray("senses");

        JSONObject d = sensesArray.getJSONObject(0);
        JSONArray de = d.getJSONArray("definitions");

        def=de.getString(0);
        t1.setText(def);
        Toast.makeText(context,def,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Everthing is working fine in this code except that I can't get the word's meaning through edit text.

To be more specific :
The code works fine when I add
final String word = "car";
in dictionaryEntries() under Mainactivity.java

but nothing is displayed when :
final String word = et.getText().toString();

Comment: that is beacuse EditText is still empty when you call that code.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I have passed it through the url?

Comment: yes, you are building the URL before you enter anything into the edittext

Answer (score 0):

you have to move one of your code :

```
public void requestApiButtonClick(View v) {
    MyDictionaryRequest myDictionaryRequest = new MyDictionaryRequest(this, t1);
    url = dictionaryEntries();
    myDictionaryRequest.execute(url);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain that further? Which parts have you adjusted, and why?